# Cyberduck Google Drive connection error

Tags: google, ftp, google-apps

I've downloaded Cyberduck for Mac. I'm using Mojave 10.14.6 and Cyberduck 7.2.2

I have a google drive 2T account (Google One now) and my Google Backup and Sync is working fine.

I open cyberduck and click on `New Connection->Google Drive` and I click on `Connect`

A Chorme page opens where I select my account, and I get the following message:

```
Sign in with google temporarily disabled for this app
This app has not been verified yet by Google in order to use Google Sign In
```

Any ideas of what is going on and how to solve?

Answer (score 1):

> **Unverified app user cap**
>   To protect users and Google systems from abuse, apps that use OAuth and Cloud Identity have certain quota restrictions based on the risk level of the OAuth scopes an app uses.
>
> [Sign in with Google temporarily disabled window]
>
> To remove these screens from your app, or to prevent your app from being marked as risky, you need to go through the verification process.

and

> When your app is successfully verified, the unverified app screen is removed from your client.

... talk to developers and expect them to take action.

> If you were using an app and you were redirected here from an error page, wait one day before you try to use the app again. This should allow the app total new user cap to refresh. If you continue to get an error, the owner of the app might need to take action before you and other new users can access it.

https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865